# Call webservice in ios , backend is Python and Google app engine

Tags: ios, google-app-engine

Server is using google app engine cloud app end points 
backend is python and google app Engine. How to access service in iOS app.?

Comment: via http/json? are you saying your iOS app can't hit your server?

Comment: I have no idea how to generate GTLService class and all that .